# Will clean Ubuntu installation remove WIndows 8 OEM Product Key?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8

I have Dell windows 8 based PC. I read on blog that Win 8 product key is stored in Bios. What happened when I will install fresh clean ubuntu on Dell? Will it remove that product key too?

Please advise me.

Thanks

Comment: Try the http://SuperUser.com stack - not strictly programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product key stored in the bios will not be removed.  However, you want to make sure you've created recovery media (or maintain your recovery partition).

Dell no longer includes recovery media with new systems.  Instead there might be a recovery partition that allows you to reinstall Windows.  As I never really trust myself to install new OS's without messing with other partitions, I always want to make additional recovery media.

You can create your own recovery DVD or USB stick by using the **Dell backup and recovery software** which should be preinstalled.

Once you have a copy of your recovery media (in case you decide to go back to Windows 8 in the future), I would say you're good to install Ubuntu.  Just make sure that you pay attention to the documentation.  Windows 8 install is a little different as a result of UEFI and SecureBoot.

See this thread on AskUbuntu;

[Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/a/228069/16747)